# How to select a week from a database using a query, without using specific years

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

I have a database with a lot of dates. I need to create a query that can help me make a dataframe of the dates I'm interested in. I need to select the dates from 25 to 31 october, without selecting specific years. I currently only have this, selecting only one date

```
query_week = '''
SELECT [ID]
FROM dates
WHERE [ID] IN
    (Select [ID]
    FROM movies
    WHERE Genre = 'Horror'
    AND (Date LIKE \"%-10-25\"));
'''
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:

```
query_week = """
SELECT [ID]
FROM dates
WHERE [ID] IN
    (Select [ID]
    FROM movies
    WHERE Genre = 'Horror'
    AND MONTH(CAST([Date] AS DATE)) = 10
    AND DAY(CAST([Date] AS DATE)) BETWEEN 25 AND 31);
"""
```

Keep in mind `date` is a reserved keyword in SQL so you will have to format it accordingly to whatever flavor of SQL you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately my jupyter-notebook tells me no such function: MONTH, do you have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: it would help to know the flavor of database that you are using. I assume you are running this query against a database.